# Naming conventions (letter case, underscores, &c) for Coq

Tags: coq, soft-question

Does Coq have an established convention/style for constructors, variables, terms, &c?

An established convention that isn't *exceptionless* is totally fine. For example, *terms should be lowercase like `nat` unless you're trying to mimic math notation in cases like `N` or `Z`* is a good convention.

---

The naming convention I've started using for toy Coq code is `PascalCase` for variables and constructors and `snake_case` for everything else.

I like being able to visually distinguish variables and nonvariables at a glance, and like naming single-argument constructors after the type of their argument, which is possible in this convention.

However, using the same portion of the namespace for constructors and variables leads to problems.

In this code snippet, `MisspelledConstructor` is a variable and will unify with anything. This problem is not huge is practice because Coq enforces exhaustiveness in match statements, but distinguishing constructors and variables by convention would lead to more informative error messages and make debugging slightly easier.

```
match thing with
| MisspelledConstructor => expression
| (* some pattern *) => (* this expression is unreachable because 
   MisspelledConstructor matches everything *)
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A similar question was recently discussed in the Coq Zulip chat ([regular link](https://coq.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/styleguide), [no-login-needed link](https://coq.gitlab.io/zulip-archive/stream/237977-Coq-users/topic/styleguide.html)), of which this answer is a summary.

The [vstyle](https://vstyle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) project is working on building / collecting Coq style conventions.

Some specific libraries have their own conventions. For example:

- [MathComp](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)
- [Iris](https://gitlab.mpi-sws.org/iris/iris/-/wikis/style-guide)
- [HoTT](https://github.com/HoTT/HoTT/blob/master/STYLE.md)
- [Verdi](https://github.com/uwplse/verdi/blob/master/STYLE.md)

See also [Deep Generation of Coq Lemma Names Using Elaborated Terms](https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.07761) and  [Learning to Format Coq Code Using Language Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.16743) for more references.